# Flutter | How to trim data that is coming from API which is displaying at UI in the form of String

Tags: arrays, string, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

'This is the json which I am getting'

```
{
"data": {
    "attributes": {
        "serverDate": "2022-02-03T07:07:50.231Z",
        "totalBills": [
            {                                   
                "dueDate": "Tue Jan 04 2022 19:24:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
               }
             ]
           }
          }
         }
```

this is my code which in UI part
`Text( order.data.attributes.totalBills[0].dueDate),`

I want to show output like this in UI "Jan 04 2022".

Comment: use `https://pub.dev/packages/intl`package to format the DateTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
Text( order.data.attributes.totalBills[0].dueDate.substring(3,16));
```

3 and 16 are the range of index(int) of starting and ending position.

Answer (score 0):

```
   DateFormat('MMM dd y HH:mm')
   .format(DateTime.parse(
   order.data.attributes.totalBills[0].toString()))
  .toString()
```

This is How you can parse .

thanks

Answer (score 0):

By using [intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) you can format the date string. For example,

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd().format(DateTime.parse(order.data.attributes.totalBills[0].dueDate));
```